# UIViewController's view changes dimension immediately after being presented

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I would like a view controller's view to be presented just it is in the nib, but the dimensions are being altered when I call presentModalViewController:animated: as the following code shows:

```
CGRect frame = viewController.view.frame;
NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height); 

[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

frame = viewController.view.frame;
NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```

Output:

```
0.000000 0.000000 297.000000 452.000000
0.000000 0.000000 540.000000 620.000000
```

What is causing this change and what can I do to prevent it?

I am aware I can insert

```
viewController.view.superview.frame = frame;
```

immediately after presenting, but this seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in developer.apple discussion about `presentModalViewController:animated:`

**Discussion**

Sets the modalViewController property to the specified view controller. **Resizes** its view and attaches it to the view hierarchy. The view is animated according to the transition style specified in the modalTransitionStyle property of the controller in the modalViewController parameter.

Comment: I'm supposing then that this behavior can't be disabled.